# ¿Como cargar automaticamente en formato numerico, los valores que se exportaron en excel desde Ireport ?

Tags: ireport

Al exportar como excel un reporte hecho en Ireport , hay cierto valores numéricos que se cargan como texto al abrirlo en excel, a pesar de que dichas celdas esta con formato Bigdecimal en el ireport.
Mi pregunta es ¿si es posible configurar automáticamente para que el excel los cargue en formato numérico mismo.?

De antemano gracias por cualquier aporte.

Answer (score 0):

Al realizar un poco de investigación me encontré con este post que me resulto útil

https://community.jaspersoft.com/questions/540379/automatically-converting-numbers-stored-text-numbers-when-export-excel-ireport

En el cual detalla qye   se debe editar el archivo .jxrml y agregar en su contenido esta propiedad
 
Finalmente al generar el reporte todos los valores se cargaron automáticamente en formato numérico.